# why doesn't systemd start automatically on boot from beagleboard

Tags: systemd, boot, yocto

I have built beagleboard images (core-image-minimal, core-image-base and core-image-sata) with yocto poke, after linux kernel (v5.19) starts, I don't see systemd starts unlike debian or angstrom distribution, it ends up following

[    4.407501] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.411468] hub 1-0:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    4.417449] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.426116] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.435791] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.444763] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.454254] printk: console [netcon0] enabled
[    4.458648] netconsole: network logging started
[    4.464599] input: gpio_keys as /devices/platform/gpio_keys/input/input2
[    4.473297] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.482727] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.491271] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.506164] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.513366] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    4.523681] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    4.528900] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    4.700256] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-omap
[    4.902679] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.906738] hub 1-2:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    4.914337] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.923370] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.933502] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.942230] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.230163] usb 1-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-omap
[    5.385650] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdda_video not found, using dummy regulator
[    5.394653] omapdss_dss 48050000.dss: supply vdds_dsi not found, using dummy regulator
[   14.580322] random: crng init done
[   35.060394] VAUX3: disabling
[   35.064178] VDAC: disabling
[   35.067413] VMMC1: disabling
[   35.071533] VUSB3V1: disabling
[   35.075042] VPLL2: disabling

test new kernels on beagloboard-xm by yocto, but it hangs somewhere, any idea or how to debug it?